# android adding a java library causes errors in runtime?

Tags: android, android-studio, telegram-bot

i'm tring to add [this library](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots) to an android app in android studio. when i add it by jar it will not give me errors, and it will try to build but never finishes. when i try to adding it by the gradle
compile "org.telegram:telegrambots:3.0.1"
it will build but gives me some runtime err:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Lambda coming from jar file need their 
interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are 
java.util.function.Predicate","sources":
[{"file":"C:\\Users\\soshiant\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Glassbutton3\\ 
DefaultBotSession.java","position":{"startLine":215,"endLine":216}}]} AGPBI:     
{"kind":"error","text":"Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on 
the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are 
java.util.function.Function","sources":
[{"file":"C:\\Users\\soshiant\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Glassbutton3\\ 
DefaultBotSession.java","position":{"startLine":216,"endLine":217}}]} AGPBI: 
{"kind":"error","text":"Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on 
the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are 
java.util.Comparator","sources":
[{"file":"C:\\Users\\soshiant\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Glassbutton3\\ 
DefaultBotSession.java","position":{"startLine":217,"endLine":218}}]}
```

i dont know if its relevant but building it gives warnings like this :

```
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3 is 
ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version 
provided by Android. In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to 
change the class packages WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 
is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version 
provided by Android. In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to 
change the class packages
```

the project is an empty activity and doesn't have any code in it just the lib is added. 
I have previously worked with this library in a Java program and it works flawlessly.
i dont know what i'm doing wrong in adding this library.i've tried it with multiple combination of sdkbuild versions and targetsdk's to no avail.

i've tried different versions of this library too it gives me similar errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TelegramBots require java 8.

Android supports java 8 but not completely. You can check here what is supported and how to enable java8 support: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

Even since android supports all the features that are present today in TelegramBots, you don't know if any unsupported feature will be added in the future so I would not use this library in an android project.

Comment: what would be the alternative ? what should i use instead of this library ?

Comment: @SoshiantDavid you can find if something wrote a library and is supporting java 7 or you can work with telegram bots api directly